# Egit removed my project from workspace

Tags: eclipse, git, maven

I created ear project with New->Other->Maven project. I chose wildfly-javaee7-webapp-ear-blank-archetype (8.2.0.Final), which created structure like this:

[image]

And then on Git perspective I chose "Create new local git repository" (in my home folder/git/WebTest). Now I choose Team->Share Project, choose my repository folder and finish.

And I end up with completely destroyed folder structure in my workspace:

[image]

I have no files under web/ear/ejb, I cannot run this app, I cannot work on it. What am I doing wrong? Another question - what is the first folder from the top? So far when I was creating an ear app I had only ear, ejb, war/web folders.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the GUI doesn't behave as expected, it is best to fall back to the CLI (Command-Line Interface), before switching back to the GUI.

From Eclipse, recreate your project as before.

Then, in the CLI, go to the root folder of that project, and type:

```
git init .
echo bin/>.gitignore
echo *.class>.gitignore
echo *.jar>.gitignore
echo *.war>.gitignore
echo *.ear>.gitignore
git config user.name yourUsername
git config user.email yourEmail
git add -A .
git commit -m "new project"
```

Then switch back to Eclipse, [switch to a new workspace](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-workspaceswitch.htm) and [import your existing Git repo.](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories)

(For the .gitignore, I followed [`gitignore/Java.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Java.gitignore)).